# Module xxx not found, required by xxx

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, java-module

I'm trying to build a small program in Eclipse 2020-06 using Java14. I have [Guava 29](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/29.0-jre) as a dependency. Here is my `module-info.java`

```
module xxx {

   exports main;

   requires java.base;
   requires java.desktop;
   requires java.prefs;
   requires com.google.common;
}
```

However, when I launch the program, I get this message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.google.common not found, required by xxx
```

The guava jar is placed under Modulepath. I'm not using any build tools like Maven etc.

---

After removing the `requires`, I checked what the compiler would suggest. Here is what the compiler suggests as a requires, but I already had it before.
See: https://prnt.sc/unp2hf

Comment: What error occurs if you remove `requires com.google.common;`?

Comment: After I remove the `requires` and the lines that use guava, the program launches fine.

Comment: Why did you add it, then?

Comment: Because I need to use the library.

Comment: Ise the the library like normal, the compiler error will show you the correct module. I think you just put the wrong module name, there.

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: I've done what you suggested, please see the updated post.

Comment: Retry after delete the existing run configuration. What is the reason to have the `module-info.java` file in your case? Does it work without the `module-info.java` file? If all these does not help, please show your run configuration the tab _Dependencies_.

Comment: It does run without the `module-info.java` as long as I move guava dependency from Modulepath to classpath. I want to have the `module-info.java` though, I may use what I wrote as a library in the future and I want to have it modularized.

Comment: Moving the dependency from modulepath to classpath should not be necessary. It seems something is wrong with your run configuration. So please show it. I have seen a few times that people mistakenly specify VM arguments by following tutorials made for the command line (in this case moving a dependency from modulepath to classpath can actually lead to different behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem. First, move the dependencies to a folder called
***modules*** in your projects root folder. and then add them to the modulepath.

[image]

Then, in the same window, click Source and edit the Default Output Folder to

> PROJECT_NAME/modules/MODULE_NAME

[image]

and happily launch the program.